# How to categorize unduplicate data using Java by grouping?

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap, java-stream

Here I am trying to group data in by object_type and object_name and from that I need to create json structure according to the output given below.  I am not sure how should I proceed, I have tried with some piece of code but failed , If someone could guide me how to move ahead it would be of great help , here I want to group it by object_type and secondly by object_name

```
public class Entity {

    private String object_type;
    private String object_name;
    private String permission_type;
    private String is_enabled;
    
    
    public Entity(String object_type, String object_name, String permission_type, String is_enabled) {
        this.object_type = object_type;
        this.object_name = object_name;
        this.permission_type = permission_type;
        this.is_enabled = is_enabled;
    }

    public class ResultEntity {
        public final String object_type;
        public final List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permission_type;
        public final Set<String> object_name;
    
        public ResultEntity(String object_type, List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permission_type, Set<String> object_name) {
            this.object_type = object_type;
            this.permission_type = permission_type;
            this.object_name = object_name;
        }
    }
```

And then, with the example data that you provided, this:

```
public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
        entities.add(new Entity("Builder", "App Builder", "VIEW", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("Builder", "App Builder", "EDIT", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "planning", "VIEW", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "planning", "EDIT", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "Localization", "VIEW", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General ", "Localization", "EDIT", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General ", "Localization", "clone", "true"));

        List<ResultEntity> res = createResult(entities);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(res));
    }

    private static List<ResultEntity> createResult(List<Entity> entities) {
        Map<String, List<Entity>> map = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getObject_type));

        List<ResultEntity> result = map.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            String objectType = entry.getKey();
            Set<String> objectNames = entry.getValue().stream().map(Entity::getObject_name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permissions = entry.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entity -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entity.getPermission_type(), entity.getIs_enabled()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new ResultEntity(objectType, permissions, objectNames);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return result;
    }
}
```

would produce this:

```
    [ {
  "object_type" : "Builder",
  "permission_type" : [ 
    {"VIEW" : "true" }, 
    {"EDIT" : "true"}
    ],
  "object_name" : [ "App Builder" ]
}, {
  "object_type" : "General",
  "permission_type" : [ 
    {"VIEW" : "true"},
    {"EDIT" : "true" }, 
    {"VIEW" : "true" }
    ],
  "object_name" : [ "planning", "Localization" ]
}, {
  "object_type" : "General ",
  "permission_type" : [ 
    {   "EDIT" : "true" },
    {   "clone" : "true"}
    ],
  "object_name" : [ "Localization" ]
} ]
```

but the output required is something like this:

```
    [ {
      "object_type" : "Builder",
      "permission_type" : [ 
        { "VIEW" : "true"}, 
        {"EDIT" : "true"}
        ],
      "object_name" : [ "App Builder" ]
    }, 
{
      "object_type" : "General",
      "permission_type" : [   
        { "VIEW" : "true"}, 
        {"EDIT" : "true"} 
        ],
      "object_name" : [ "planning" ]
      }, 
{
      "object_type" : "General ",
      "permission_type" : [ 
        { "VIEW" : "true"},
        { "EDIT" : "true"}, 
        {"clone" : "true"}
        ],
      "object_name" : [ "Localization" ]
    } ]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the requirement? I don't understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I have edited the question pls check

Comment: The example code that you shared does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this method helped

```
private static List<ResultEntity> createResult(List<Entity> entities) {
        Map<String, List<Entity>> map = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getObject_name));
        Map<String, String> objTypes = entities.stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getObject_name, Entity::getObject_type, (a1, a2) -> a1));
        List<ResultEntity> result = map.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            Set<String> entObjName = new HashSet<String>();
            List<Entry<String, Boolean>> permissions = entry.getValue().stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getObject_name().equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey()))
                    .map(entity -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entity.getPermission_type(), entity.getIs_enabled()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            entObjName.add(entry.getKey());
            return new ResultEntity(objTypes.get(entry.getKey()), permissions, entObjName );
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the JSON representation which I think you are wanting, where the permissions are an array of objects, you could change the type for `ResultEntry::permission_type` from `Map<String, String>` to `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`:

```
public class ResultEntity {
    public final String object_type;
    public final List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permission_type;
    public final Set<String> object_name;

    public ResultEntity(String object_type, List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permission_type, Set<String> object_name) {
        this.object_type = object_type;
        this.permission_type = permission_type;
        this.object_name = object_name;
    }
}
```

And then, with the example data that you provided, this:

```
public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
        entities.add(new Entity("Builder", "App Builder", "VIEW", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("Builder", "App Builder", "EDIT", "false"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "planning", "VIEW", "false"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "planning", "EDIT", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General", "Localization", "VIEW", "false"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General ", "Localization", "EDIT", "true"));
        entities.add(new Entity("General ", "Localization", "clone", "true"));

        List<ResultEntity> res = createResult(entities);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(res));
    }

    private static List<ResultEntity> createResult(List<Entity> entities) {
        Map<String, List<Entity>> map = entities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getObject_type));

        List<ResultEntity> result = map.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            String objectType = entry.getKey();
            Set<String> objectNames = entry.getValue().stream().map(Entity::getObject_name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> permissions = entry.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entity -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entity.getPermission_type(), entity.getIs_enabled()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new ResultEntity(objectType, permissions, objectNames);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return result;
    }
}
```

would produce this:

```
[ {
  "object_type" : "Builder",
  "permission_type" : [ {
    "VIEW" : "true"
  }, {
    "EDIT" : "false"
  } ],
  "object_name" : [ "App Builder" ]
}, {
  "object_type" : "General",
  "permission_type" : [ {
    "VIEW" : "false"
  }, {
    "EDIT" : "true"
  }, {
    "VIEW" : "false"
  } ],
  "object_name" : [ "planning", "Localization" ]
}, {
  "object_type" : "General ",
  "permission_type" : [ {
    "EDIT" : "true"
  }, {
    "clone" : "true"
  } ],
  "object_name" : [ "Localization" ]
} ]
```

Comment: Like suppose in general object name there are two names localization and planning , permissions for both are different , so needed in that format , if you can pls help in it

Comment: I have edited the question in more detailed format , pls check once